# Creating pd.dataframe from multiline String object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python and I have already found the posts here very helpful but now I am stuck.  I have parsed trading data from an email and saved it into a string object that looks like this:

=E2=84=96\tOrderID\tInstrument/ISIN\tDirection\tQuantity\t=\nPrice\tAmount\tDeal time\tSlippage\tConfirmation time\t=\nSettlement time\tCommission\tCharges and fees\tOther\n> **1**\tPO59332737\tOil-20Sep17\tBuy\t100\t46.100000\t=\n4610.00 USD\t2017-08-30 20:46:36\t0.000000\t2017-08-30 =\n21:01:47\t2017-08-30 21:01:47\t0.000000 GBP\t0.000000 GBP\t=\n-\n> **2**\tPO59332799\tOil-20Sep17\tBuy\t50\t46.100000\t=\n2305.00 USD\t2017-08-30 20:46:48\t0.000000\t2017-08-30 =\n21:01:47\t2017-08-30 21:01:47\t0.000000 GBP\t0.000000 GBP\t=\n-\n> **3**\tMO59332700\tOil-20Sep17\tBuy\t100\t46.019000\t=\n4601.90 USD\t2017-08-30 20:46:27\t0.000000\t2017-08-30 =\n20:46:27\t2017-08-30 20:46:27\t0.000000 GBP\t0.000000 GBP\t=\n-\n>

The string continues but the structure is the same: The column headers ('=E2=84=96', Order ID', ..., 'Other') are followed by the specific values. The snippet shows 3 rows of data.
Columns are separated with \t and new rows in the email start with \n .

My goal is turn this string into a pandas dataframe object but I am struggling to do so. I have tried replacing **\t** and **\n** with **;** and then saving the String as StringIO object and using pd.read_csv to create a dataframe from the string. However this puts all the data into separate columns so that I end up with 0 rows.

How I can manipulate the string object such that pd.read_csv automatically recognises when a new row starts. In csv files a new row starts with a new line, however, in my string all rows are joined together.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT: I have realised that new rows in the string start with **\n>**. How can I use this to specify when a new row in the dataframe should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A messy one.

The first thing I did, having saved that text to a file, was to split it on the `\\n`s, to make it easier to understand, and write out the pieces. This enabled me to see several features of the data:

- There are three lines of 'header' and then three lines in each 'record', if I ignore the inconsequential lines consisting of just a '-'.
- I could collapse the '>' out of existence.
- Pandas is happy with tab characters. I could replace each '\t' with a tab.

.

```
>>> with open('simon.txt') as simon:
...     for line in simon.read().split('\\n'):
...         line
...         
'=E2=84=96\\tOrderID\\tInstrument/ISIN\\tDirection\\tQuantity\\t='
'Price\\tAmount\\tDeal time\\tSlippage\\tConfirmation time\\t='
'Settlement time\\tCommission\\tCharges and fees\\tOther'
'> 1\\tPO59332737\\tOil-20Sep17\\tBuy\\t100\\t46.100000\\t='
'4610.00 USD\\t2017-08-30 20:46:36\\t0.000000\\t2017-08-30 ='
'21:01:47\\t2017-08-30 21:01:47\\t0.000000 GBP\\t0.000000 GBP\\t='
'-'
'> 2\\tPO59332799\\tOil-20Sep17\\tBuy\\t50\\t46.100000\\t='
'2305.00 USD\\t2017-08-30 20:46:48\\t0.000000\\t2017-08-30 ='
'21:01:47\\t2017-08-30 21:01:47\\t0.000000 GBP\\t0.000000 GBP\\t='
'-'
'> 3\\tMO59332700\\tOil-20Sep17\\tBuy\\t100\\t46.019000\\t='
'4601.90 USD\\t2017-08-30 20:46:27\\t0.000000\\t2017-08-30 ='
'20:46:27\\t2017-08-30 20:46:27\\t0.000000 GBP\\t0.000000 GBP\\t='
'-'
'>'
```

- As I read through the input file I number each line in `n`. Skipped lines, ie, those that contain only a hyphen, are not counted.
- When I accumulate three lines of input in `big_line` I join them together, replace the '\t' characters with tabs and write the result to the output file. Then I reset `big_line` to empty, ready for the next three lines.

.

```
>>> with open('simon.txt') as simon:
...     with open('simon_out.txt', 'w') as simon_out:
...         n = 0   
...         big_line = []
...         for line in simon.read().split('\\n'):
...             if line=='-':
...                 pass
...             else:
...                 n += 1
...                 if n % 3 == 1:
...                     if big_line:
...                         simon_out.write(' '.join(big_line).replace('\\t', '\t')+'\n')
...                         big_line = []
...                 line = line.replace('>', '')
...                 big_line.append(line)
...                 
157
157
156
157
```

The result is acceptable to pandas. It might still need some massaging, depending on your requirements.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('simon_out.txt', sep='\t')
>>> df
   =E2=84=96     OrderID Instrument/ISIN Direction  Quantity  = Price  \
0          1  PO59332737     Oil-20Sep17       Buy       100   46.100   
1          2  PO59332799     Oil-20Sep17       Buy        50   46.100   
2          3  MO59332700     Oil-20Sep17       Buy       100   46.019   

          Amount            Deal time  Slippage      Confirmation time  \
0  = 4610.00 USD  2017-08-30 20:46:36       0.0  2017-08-30 = 21:01:47   
1  = 2305.00 USD  2017-08-30 20:46:48       0.0  2017-08-30 = 21:01:47   
2  = 4601.90 USD  2017-08-30 20:46:27       0.0  2017-08-30 = 20:46:27   

     = Settlement time    Commission Charges and fees Other  
0  2017-08-30 21:01:47  0.000000 GBP     0.000000 GBP     =  
1  2017-08-30 21:01:47  0.000000 GBP     0.000000 GBP     =  
2  2017-08-30 20:46:27  0.000000 GBP     0.000000 GBP     =
```

Comment: many thanks for the code and particularly for the comments, so I could understand what's going on between the lines. Have applied your method and successfully created a pd.dataframe object.